# Understanding advanced frameworks. In what order is controller, directive, css, services executed in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

In what order is controller, directive, css, services, factories etc. executed in Angular.js when you observe the console log/browser output? I'm observing a TV-streaming app project in angular at my current company and I'm having a hard time grasping how & when all these parts are executed and how they connect. I assume it’s a linear synchronous process but how.

Is there any visual explanation of how this works in detail? I seen many diagrams of two way data binding concept, but its very superficial and it does not clarify how each component of the code impacts the rest. For example if i change a variable i the controller, what get impacted and how does the rest of the code now know how to process this data?

I'm used to small javascript apps that synchronously execute. I can set breakpoints and observe what is executing when. But with Angular (& react as well) it seems everything happens at once and can't grasp what happens when and where. It seems like an overwhelming grid of connections with little documentation on when/how/why.

When and where does the different Angular sections/components execute? 
I'm looking for an explanation similar to [this](https://medium.com/@kvosswinkel/is-javascript-synchronous-or-asynchronous-what-the-hell-is-a-promise-7aa9dd8f3bfb) but in relation to all the Angular(React as well) components or generally for most frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference these frameworks provide compared to just regular Plain JS is the fact that that they abstract away the DOM updates and data bindings. Now this might seem like a simple thing, but doing it correctly and in a performant way isn't easy in a synchronous fashion, as the app would become laggy when something updates and whole app gets updated at once.

In AngularJS, there is a special batched update cycle, called `$digest` cycle, which performs all DOM checks, observes changes to variables and updates all the data bindings. It gets activated by user interaction (click, hover, scroll, etc.), network requests and periodically.

The gist of how it works is:

- An event happens.
- AngularJS triggers a new cycle.
- Your JS code runs.
- AngularJS runs a diff on your scope variables to find changes & updates the DOM, if necessary.

This means that code can be processed in non-linear fashion and in batches, and thus it makes it so that the data seems to update at the same time at once.

If you want to learn more about the compilation and take a deeper dive in AngularJS's internals, this is a good starting point https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/docs/api/ng/service/$compile as well as https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/docs/guide/scope

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answer, the "magical thing" you should be looking at is the AngularJs Digest cycle.

1. Angular uses events in custom directives like ng-click or ng-keyup
2. The event is handled by Angular Context ($scope) which has watchers to check if any property has changed.
3. Angular does that by using $digest which goes through all the watchers

This entire process is called a digest cycle.

Official docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

For a more visual approach, you may follow the three Digest Cycle videos on Coursera:
https://www.coursera.org/lecture/single-page-web-apps-with-angularjs/lecture-14-part-1-digest-cycle-DeEZV